# Async/Await on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, actions-on-google

I'm trying to deploy a Webhook for Dialogflow in an Action-On-Google.

This Webhook is using Async/Await, so it needs NodeJS 8.x.

When I type "node --version" into my Google Cloud console (the one on cloud.google.com website), it shows me 8.5.0 as version of node.

But when I deploy the webhook script via "gcloud beta functions deploy", I get a "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" at the position of my script where the first "await" is used.

So is async/await disabled in the Google Cloud, even if it is using Node 8.5?

Answer (score 3):

Google Cloud Functions (aka Firebase Functions) only supports node 6.11.5 (see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/ for details). Thus, you can only use language features supported up to that version of node.

Comment: And why does the Google Cloud console show version 8.5.0? Is this different from Google Cloud functions?

Comment: It is, yes. The console is effectively a small VM with some tools intsalled that you can use for development, scripting against and interacting with GCP. Google Cloud Functions are separate, sandboxed functions running at scale, and thus use an older LTS release of Node.js.

Comment: The Node version on Google App Engine is 8

Comment: You can take advantage of Node 7+ features (like async/await) by writing your functions in Typescript or Babel. Then configure your build to transpile your files into Node 6 compatible Javascript. That way you can develop locally in whatever version of Node you want, and not have to worry about Firebase's version.